# Need Help Simulating a 502 Error on a Website

Tags: bad-gateway, http-status-code-502

I have a task that I'm struggling with and could use some assistance. The task requires me to simulate receiving a 502 error on a functioning website, such as google.com or any other site. However, I'm having difficulty finding resources or instructions on how to intentionally trigger a 502 error for testing purposes.
Could anyone provide guidance or step-by-step instructions, possibly with screenshots, on how to simulate a 502 error on a website? I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions you can offer

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Most forums and websites seem to focus on fixing this error rather than simulating it.

Comment: https://httpstat.us/ can generate any status code you like, e.g. https://httpstat.us/502